# Regex to match number with different digits and minimum length

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I am trying to write a regex (to validate a property on a c# .NET Core model, which generates javascript expression) to match all numbers composed by at least two different digits and a minimum length of 6 digits.

For example:

222222 - not valid

122222 - valid

1111125 - valid

I was trying the following expression: `(\d)+((?!\1)(\d))` , which matches the sequence if has different digits but how can I constrain the size of the whole pattern to `{6,}`  ?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you had time to check my answer? Please check if it works the way you epxect.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?=\d{6})(\d)\1*(?!\1)\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uaf1Az/5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\d{6})` - at least 6 digits
- `(\d)` - any digit is captured into Group 1
- `\1*` - zero or more occurrences of the value captured in Group 1
- `(?!\1)` - the next digit cannot be the same as in Group 1
- `\d+` - 1+digits
- `$` - end of string.