# Regular Expression in JavaScript having exactly 6 digits and at least two different digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make sure that I have exactly 6 digits and not all of them are the same (222222 is not acceptable but 122222 or 211111 or 122223 are acceptable).

I am using [this](https://regex101.com/r/Uaf1Az/5):

```
    ^(?=\d{6})(\d)\1*(?!\1)\d+$
```

But this only satisfies `minimum` 6 digits and not `exactly` 6 digits.

(source: [Regex to match number with different digits and minimum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402863/regex-to-match-number-with-different-digits-and-minimum-length))

Comment: Just add an anchor (`$`) to your first lookahead i.e. `(?=\d{6}$)` https://regex101.com/r/Uaf1Az/16

Answer (score 3):

You may use this bit simplified and more efficient regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{5}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqFhEj/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^(\d)`: Match and capture a digit at the start
- `(?!\1+$)`: Negative lookahead to assert that same digit is not repeated till end.
- `\d{5}$`: Add 5 more digits before end

Comment: @moh: Did this work out?